# Set @Value to use @ConfigurationProperties prefix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using a properties file with the value:
`com.abc.cpuUtilization.okThreshold = 0.5`

I want to use the following configuration class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.abc")
public class SystemConfiguration{

  @Value("${cpuUtilization.okThreshold}")
  private Double cpuUtilizationOkThreshold;

  // getters and setters of cpuUtilizationOkThreshold
  }
}
```

But I get an exception of `Could not resolve placeholder 'cpuUtilization.okThreshold'`

When setting `@Value` to be: `"${com.abc.cpuUtilization.okThreshold}"` it works, but it makes the code look ugly and cumbersome.

Is there a way to configure this class, so I will not have to write the whole prefix for the `@Value` annotation?

Comment: I encounter similar issue as well, and also not sure why spring simply don't allow us to use Value("${cpuUtilization.okThreshold}").  It forces us to create another ConfigurationProperties annotated class to represent the cpuUtilization.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing. Imo it's error prone if one has to rely on the field name, which can be refactored and break things. So you need validation and tests on top to ensure properties are loaded correctly. Best solution seems to be to avoid `@ConfigurationProperties` and just work with plain `@Value`

Answer (score 3):

Spring configuration properties scanning works like package scanning.

The `@Value` annotation works with the full property name, or a raw `string` value. And so the value you set should be.
Assume to have the `com.abc.cpu-utilization.okThreshold=0.5` property.

- *Solution 1:* your `SystemConfiguration` modify the `prefix` and delete the `@Value`:

  ```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Configuration
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.abc.cpu-utilization")
  public class SystemConfiguration {
     private Double okThreshold;
  }
  ```
- *Solution 2:* your `SystemConfiguration` could point to *com.abc* and contain an inner configuration for the `cpu-utilization` intermediate package:

  ```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  @Configuration
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.abc")
  public class SystemConfiguration {
     private CpuUtilizationConfig cpuUtilization;
  }

  @Data
  public class CpuUtilizationConfig {
      private Double okThreshold;
  }
  ```

Note that `okThreshold` and `cpuUtilization` directly reflect the property naming we have prior defined. Then, Spring will do the magic :-)

See:

- [Baeldung - Guide to @ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)
- [Baeldung - A Quick Guide to Spring @Value](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Comment: If we do not want the field name "cpuUtilization" to reflect the property name, wat other alternative do we have?

Comment: Strange..I use try out your solution to deal with my similar issue.  I notice that the cpuUtilization field will always be null, unless i annotate this field will Autowired. At same time, i add the ConfigurationProperties (prefix = "cpuUtilization") to the CpuUtilizationConfig class.   Seems to work.  I using spring boot 2.6.2

Comment: But why would you want the property name and field name to not match? That seems needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

As thepaoloboi said, The @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.abc") annotation will allow you to bind fields via their name. If you specify a prefix of "com.abc" and you have a variable named "cpuUtilization", the value of the variable will be that of the "com.abc.cpuUtilization" property.

The @Value annotation fetches the property with the exact same name. @Value("${cpuUtilization.threshold}") will fetch the property with that exact name. It does not take the prefix into account.

Comment: The @Value annotation fetches the property with the exact same name. @Value("${cpuUtilization.threshold}") will fetch the property with that exact name. It does not take the prefix into account. 

Is this sentence really valid?  I have tried using Value annotation in inside my ConfigurationProperties annotated class, and it did take prefix into account. Fyi, the Value annotation in my class does not contain dot.

Answer (score 0):

For congiuation propertiestion you just need to add the values in proeprties file with the same key with the variable.

in application.properties.

```
com.abc.cpuUtilization.okThreshold=123
```

Your class should be:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.abc.cpuUtilization")
public class SystemConfiguration{

  private Double okThreshold;

  }
}
```

Comment: I want the prefix to be "com.abc" and control the name of the property by using Value

Comment: I agree with chens.   If u are to put the prefix to com.abc.cpuUtilization, instead of "com.abc",  then u are not able to reuse the same class for other key such as com.abc.test

Answer (score 0):

The `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.abc")` annotation will allow you to bind fields via their name. As @Olgun YILDIZ stated, if you specify a prefix of "com.abc" and you have a variable named "cpuUtilization" , the value of the variable will be that of the "com.abc.cpuUtilization" property. (In fact, you could even name your variable "cpuutilization" , "cpu_utilization" , "cpu-utilization" or "CPU_UTILIZATION" because of Spring's relaxed rules for binding properties).

The @Value annotation fetches the property with the exact same name. `@Value("${cpuUtilization.threshold}")` will fetch the property with that exact name. It does not take the prefix into account.

Either you do as @Olgun suggested (prefix of "com.abc.cpuUtilization" and variable name "okThreshold" ) or you set the whole property name in the `@Value`.

Answer (score 0):

@ConfigurationProperties works best with hierarchical properties that all have the same prefix therefore, you add a prefix of com.abc.cpuUtilization.Your POJO class Should be like

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.abc.cpuUtilization")
public class SystemConfiguration{

  private Double okThreshold;

  public Double getOkThreshold() {
        return okThreshold;
    }

    public void setOkThreshold(Double okThreshold) {
        this.okThreshold = okThreshold;
    }

  }
}
```

If you don't use @Configuration in the POJO, then you need to add @EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class) in the main Spring application class to bind the properties into the POJO.
Then you can set value in application.properties

```
com.abc.cpuUtilization.okThreshold=0.5
```

Refer:https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change your "cpuUtilization.okThreshold" value to `com.abc.cpuUtilization-okThreshold = 0.5`

Then in the config class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("com.abc")
public class SystemConfiguration{

  private Double cpuUtilizationOkThreshold;

  // getters and setters of cpuUtilizationOkThreshold
  }
}
```

Try to configure without using "prefix" and without using the @Value annotation, it worked for me.